# procedure which check data with specific date and rewrite it in

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I am tying to wright procedure which will check my history table and rewrite records in it. It must  replace recorded which were inserted in this month and only if they are in duplicated in new insert.

for now i have this procedure which  just copied clients with status id in 1 and 2 , but  if i will call it again it will duplicate records.

```
create procedure sp_MonthlyInsertInHistory
as

INSERT History( ClientId, CategCode)
  SELECT  ClientId, CategCode   
  FROM dbo.Clients 
  where StatusID in (1,2)
go
```

History table looks like

```
Historyid(int) auto increment, ClienID (int), CategCode (varchar), RecordDate (date)GETDATE();

    1, 11, SR, 2013-02-01
    2, 12, CH, 2013-02-01
    3, 11, SR, 2013-03-01
    4, 12, CH, 2013-03-01
```

If i will run this procedure it should delete record `11, 1, 2013-03-01` and replace it  with `11, 1, 2013-03-18`current date, and if clientid 12 right now not in statusid 1 or 2 but it is already in table it should stay there. However it should not delete records if they were created not in this month or not in select in insert statement. (for example new clients). I hope you will understand my explanation.
Any help appreciated because I just do not know from what to start.

Comment: Is the bit you are stuck with Updating records in history for "this" month if there status id is 1 or 2?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson yes and no it should not only update it also should insert clientsid which are not there yet but in client table now. I was thinking to delete records which in my select for insert and then insert records from select which i have right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help you.

```
create procedure sp_MonthlyInsertHistory
as
begin
  merge History as target
  using (SELECT ClientID, CategCode from clients where statusid in (1,2)) as source (ClientID, CategCode)
  on (target.ClientID = source.ClientID and DATEDIFF(mm,target.RecordDate,GETDATE())=0)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
      UPDATE SET target.CategCode = Source.CategCode, 
                 target.RecordDate=GetDATE()
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (ClientID,CategCode)
      VALUES (source.ClientID,source.CategCode);
END
```